# Babel cli - Passing nested options to

Tags: babeljs

I don't want to need to use .babelrc file in all cases (build script) but can't seem to find a syntax to pass nested options to the CLI. Here is a simplified version of my .babelrc that I need to pass on the command line:

`{"presets": [ ["es2015", { "modules": false }] ], "compact": true }`

Anyone know the syntax for this?

Answer (score 4):

Babel does not currently support passing options to presets or plugins via the CLI.

Comment: Ok, but I think if Babel had such option, it would be great

Comment: No disagreement there.